# I think my lecturer has lost a factor of two

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

I have had this general feeling since I've been at uni, that if you have a good enough degree you can drop factors willy nilly, and my physics lecturer just did this in the middle of a lagrangian mechanics lecture, while changing the equation for kinetic energy $$K= \frac12 m \left(\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2\right)$$ into polar coordinates, if you resolve using $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dr}{dt}\cos\theta - r\frac{d\theta}{dt} \sin\theta$  and $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dr}{dt}\sin\theta + r\frac{d\theta}{dt}\cos\theta$ I ended up with 
$$K = \frac12 m ~ \left(2 \left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2 + 2r^2 \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2\right) $$
my lecturer ended up with half of my value inside the brackets, is this because of something to do with generalised coordinates that I'm forgetting or missing or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pythagorean theorem in trigonometric form is $$\big(\cos\theta\big)^2 + \big(\sin\theta\big)^2 = 1.$$ When you set up the expansion you should simply have $$\big(\dot r \cos \theta - r\dot \theta\sin\theta\big)^2 + \big(\dot r \sin\theta + r\dot\theta\cos\theta\big)^2$$ by substitution.

Looking at the $\dot r^2$ term for example, when we FOIL both sides we get $$(\dot r \cos\theta)^2 + (\dot r \sin\theta)^2 = \dot r^2\big((\cos\theta)^2 + (\sin\theta)^2) = \dot r^2,$$which lacks your leading two. Nothing wrong with your lecturer at all.